# SQL Query for grouped data

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to write an sql query which gives me list of clients with "Only " admin flags "N" from the below data:-

the below is a table with two columns client and admin flag

```
Client  Admin_Flag
1          Y
1          N
2          Y
3          Y
3          N
2          Y
4          Y
4          N
6          N
```

My output for the above should be only 6

Answer (score 1):

I like `group by` and `having` for this:

```
select client
from t
group by client
having min(admin_flag) = 'N' and max(admin_flag) = 'N';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select client
from your_table
group by client
having sum(case when admin_flag <> 'N' then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `first_value` function :

```
select distinct first_value(client) over (order by client desc) as last_client
  from tab
 where Admin_Flag = 'N';
```

[*Rextester Demo*](http://rextester.com/FDJVFI1151)

Answer (score 0):

`Group by` is the way to go.

```
  select client
  from Table_1
  group by client
  having count(distinct admin_flag) = 1 and max(admin_flag) = 'N'
```